# Python Slotting/Sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calendar, linear-programming

I have below sample data. What i want to do is sort the dataframe such that:

- Each category under P1,P2,P3 are split equally between 1H and 2H. Where it cannot split equally - keep the higher portion in 1H (e.g P1 has total 7 Deep - so while sorting i want 4 in 1H and 3 in 2H).
- A Half Price is always followed by Base.

Sample Code:

```
data = {'HALF':['1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H',
               '1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H',
               '2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H'],
        'P1':['Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base',
              'Base','Base','Base','Base','Half Price','Half Price','Half Price','Half Price','Half Price',
              'Half Price','Half Price','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base',
              'Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Deep','Deep','Deep','Deep','Deep',
              'Deep','Deep','Base','Base','Base','Base','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow'],
        'P2':['Half Price','Half Price','Half Price','Half Price','Half Price','Half Price','Half Price',
              'Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base',
              'Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Deep','Deep','Deep','Deep','Base','Base',
              'Base','Base','Base',
              'Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base',
              'Base','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base'],
        'P3':['Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Half Price','Half Price','Half Price',
              'Half Price','Half Price','Half Price','Half Price','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base',
              'Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow',
              'Shallow','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow','Shallow','Base','Base','Base',
              'Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried some linear programming options, without any outputs. Any help would be great. Thanks

**EDIT**:

Expected Output:

```
data = {'HALF':['1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H',
               '1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','1H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H',
               '2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H','2H'],
        'P1':['Base','Base','Base','Deep','Base','Base','Deep','Shallow','Base','Base','Half Price','Base','Base',
              'Base','Deep','Base','Base',
              'Base','Half Price','Base','Base','Base','Deep','Shallow','Base','Base','Half Price','Base','Base',
              'Deep','Half Price','Base','Base','Base','Deep','Shallow','Base','Base','Half Price','Base','Base',
              'Base','Deep','Shallow','Base','Base','Half Price','Base','Base','Base','Half Price','Base'],
        'P2':['Half Price','Base','Base','Base','Deep','Base','Base','Base','Half Price','Shallow','Base','Base',
              'Deep','Base','Base','Base','Half Price','Shallow','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base',
              'Half Price','Base','Base','Base','Half Price','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base',
              'Half Price','Shallow','Base','Base','Deep','Base','Base','Base','Half Price','Base','Base','Base',
              'Deep','Base','Base','Base'],
        'P3':['Base','Shallow','Half Price','Base','Base','Half Price','Base','Base','Base','Base','Base','Shallow',
              'Base','Half Price','Base','Shallow','Base','Base','Base','Shallow','Half Price','Shallow','Base',
              'Base','Base','Base','Base','Shallow','Base','Base','Base','Shallow','Half Price','Shallow','Base',
              'Base','Base','Base','Base','Shallow','Base','Shallow','Base','Base','Base','Shallow','Base','Half Price',
              'Base','Half Price','Base','Shallow']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: can you please write an example of the ```DataFrame``` you want?

Comment: @DeanTaler I have added it now. Thanks

Comment: I meant how do you want the df:
Half |    P1  |      P2       | P3     (headers)
1H   | Base | Half price | Base
..     | .....     | .....           |.....

Comment: @DeanTaler Yes the output will be in the same format as the original df. Only difference would be that the rows would've got sorted as per the conditions. If you run my edit code it will give you the ideal output for this issue. Thanks